# javascript scroll object by mouseover

Tags: javascript, html, dom, scroll, onmouseover

I'm trying to make it so that a div will scroll when the mouse hovers over the an image but can only scroll so far. Somewhere its just not quite working

```
$(document).ready(function()
 {
    $('#test').bind('mouseenter', function() 
   {
    var self = $(this);
    var right = parseInt(self.style.left) || 200;               
    this.iid = setInterval(function() 
     {
         if (right <= 400)
         {                     
         right += 200;                         
         }
         else
         {
          right = 400;                         
         }
    self.style.left = right + "px";
     }, 525);
   }).bind('mouseleave', function()
           {
    this.iid && clearInterval(this.iid);
           });

 });​

    #test {
        color:white;
        width: 400px; 
    height: 400px; 
    left: 200px; 
    background-color: #000; 
    position: absolute;
    }

    <div id="test">hover me please</div>​
```

or a fiddle here:
http://jsfiddle.net/qjxqC/1/

Thanks for you help

Comment: where is the function to handle the scroll event ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all don't attach a JavaScript property (iid) to a DOM reference (this) **this.iid**. This will cause memory leaks in certain browsers (IE). I'd also recommend a recursive timeout as well.

I'd use setTimeout for this operation. It provides more control given your limit check and easier break from within your function.  Here is your code reworked.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var timeout; // keep your timeout reference at a higher scope for example
    $('#test').bind({
        'mouseenter': function(){ 
            var self = $(this);
            var incrementScroll = function() {
                var left = parseInt(self.css("left"));
                if(left <= 400) {
                    self.css("left", "+=200");  // as of jQuery 1.6 you can do this
                    // self.css("left", left+200);
                    timeout = setTimeout(incrementScroll, 525);
                }
            }             
            incrementScroll();
        },
        'mouseleave': function(){
            clearTimeout(timeout);
    }});
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
var self = $(this);
```

By

```
var self = this;
```

Because `style` is a property of a DOM object, not jQuery object, but you do:

```
self.style.left = right + "px";
```